# Getting Permission denied (publickey) when login through ssh

Tags: server, permissions, aws

I have been using this since last 5 month but today I have updated `.ssh/authorised_keys` (change my directory) and also was working fine. But when  giving access to another machine (by update `.ssh/authorised_keys` (friend machine key )) then it is not working and now I am also unable to log in.

```
  $ ssh -i "dev.pem" ubuntu@ec2-11-22-9-170.ap-east1.compute.amazonaws.com
    ubuntu@ec2-11-22-9-170.ap-east1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Where did you store the private key file?  You need to pass a **full file path** to the `-i` directive unless you are in the same directory as the private key file.

Comment: yeah..it is in same directory

Comment: i have updated .ssh/authorised_keys but any other way to login and change ,ssh/authorised_key

Comment: It's `.ssh/authorized_keys` not `.ssh/authorised_keys`  (the British spelling is not the proper spelling unfortunately, to my knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your SSH setup including having the wrong file permissions on `.ssh/authorized_keys`, you will need to do a recovery process if you cannot login:

Before making any changes, create a snapshot of your system (or create an AMI) just in case you make your problem worse.

1. Start a new EC2 instance.
2. Stop the broken EC2 instance.
3. Detach the root (boot) volume from the broken EC2 instance.
4. Attach the volume to the new EC2 instance as additional disk.
5. Mount the file root file system to a temporary directory.
6. Troubleshoot and fix the problem. **In your case set the correct
   file permissions.**
7. Detach the volume from the new EC2 instance.
8. Attach the volume to the broken EC2 instance.
9. Start the broken EC2 instance.
10. Verify everything works. Go back to Step 2 to repeat.
11. Terminate the new EC2 instance when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is factory default.
I probably changed, activated "#PubkeyAuthentication yes";
that caused: Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: HDK Bouma... This should be a comment, please. I understand that you **may** not have the privilege to comment.